# JavaScript - Using the value of a variable from one function in another

Tags: javascript

I have a task to creat a simple game and I am stuck. I have a function which includes a declared variable: `var numberOfFaces = 5;`. This general function includes two another and in the second nested function I want to use value of the variable like this `numberOfFaces += 5;`but it doesn't work and after this string I still have `numberOfFaces = 5`
The full listing of a pain:

```
function generateFaces() {
  var numberOfFaces = 5;
  var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");
  var theRightSide = document.getElementById("rightSide");
  var theBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
  var counter = numberOfFaces;
  while (counter > 0) {
    var smileFaceImg = document.createElement("img");
    smileFaceImg.src = "pepe.png";
    smileFaceImg.style.top = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400) + "px";
    smileFaceImg.style.left = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400) + "px";
    theLeftSide.appendChild(smileFaceImg);
    counter--;
  }
  var clon = theLeftSide.cloneNode(true);
  clon.removeChild(clon.lastChild);
  document.getElementById("rightSide").appendChild(clon);
  theLeftSide.lastChild.onclick = function nextLevel(event) {
    while (theLeftSide.firstChild) {
      theLeftSide.removeChild(theLeftSide.firstChild);
    }
    event.stopPropagation();
    numberOfFaces += 5;
    generateFaces();
  };
  theBody.onclick = function gameOver() {
    alert("Game Over!");
    theBody.onclick = null;
    theLeftSide.lastChild.onclick = null;
  };
}
```

I'm a beginner in JavaScript. Grand merci for any help and maybe advices about "how to improve my JS skills". Best regards and good luck!

Comment: Each time you call the function you reset `numberOfFaces` to 5. You should pass `numberOfFaces` to the function as an argument, then you can do `generateFaces(numberOfFaces+5)`

Answer (score 0):

```
numberOfFaces += 5;
generateFaces();
```

You're incrementing numberOfFaces by 5, but then you're calling generateFaces() right afterwards and since this function ***resets the variable*** here:

```
function generateFaces() {
  var numberOfFaces = 5;
```

It returns the variable's value to 5.

Answer (score 0):

you want to use the numberOfFaces  as a global variable.  As carson said you should declare outside of the function

```
var numberOfFaces 
function generateFaces() {
numberOfFaces = numberOfFaces  || 5;
...
..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `generateFaces` function you are always resetting the `umberOfFaces` to `5`, you need to change your function like this:

```
function generateFaces(faces) {
  var numberOfFaces = faces ? faces : 5;
```

And then call it like this:

```
generateFaces(numberOfFaces);
```